# If statement excel between a range

Tags: database, excel, if-statement

I'm trying to create an If statement between a range which is something like:

```
If $age > 65 and $income = range(90000 to 105000) then 800 - 18.55% else NA
```

So far I've got

```
=IF(AND(E4 > 65, E4 <69, F4 > 90000, F4 < 105000), 800 * (1 - 0.1855),"NA")
```

I am getting NA when I'm trying to get 651.6. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: I'm trying to do it in excel

Comment: Thanks, That was an accident.

Comment: why do you have `database` tag? "when I'm trying to get 651.6" - do you mean it should be the result? Could you please post some screenshots? Have you tried looking step by step how your formula calculates (formulas - evaluate formula)?

Comment: E4 > 69 makes no sense looking at the sketch of your first formula, since that only checks if age greater than 65. So why are you now checking if it is between 65 and 69?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(AND(E4>64;F4>90000;F4<105001);800*0,8145;"NA")
```

Or with your locale I imagine it would be:

```
=IF(AND(E4>64,F4>90000,F4<105001),800*0.8145,"NA")
```